# Receiving this error - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of undefined

Tags: javascript

I think I'm having an ordering issue. A lot going on here and still very new to this. I have a random dot function that I'm trying to set to a div in my WP theme. I have no where to put the canvas (from what I understand...correct me if I'm wrong) so I created it in js. Anyone know what is prompting the error?

```
var c = document.createElement('canvas')[0];
var context = c.getContext('2d');


function assignToDiv() { // this kind of function you are looking for
  dataUrl = c.toDataURL();
  document.getElementsByClassName('.jupiterx-site')[0].style.background = 'url(' + dataUrl + ')'
}

function draw() {
  window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas, false);

  function resizeCanvas() {
    c.width = document.body.scrollWidth;
    c.height = 2000;


    /**
     * Circles.
     */
    drawStuff();
  }
  resizeCanvas();
}
draw();
assignToDiv();

function drawStuff() {
  // dot count
  const dots = 17;
  // max distance from the center
  const radius = 2000;

  function getRandomInt(max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
  }


  var createDots = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i <= dots; i++) {
      context.beginPath();
      const dist = (Math.random()) * radius;
      var rand_x = getRandomInt(2000);
      var rand_y = getRandomInt(8000);
      context.arc(rand_x, rand_y, 90, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
      context.fillStyle = "#ed194f";
      context.filter = "blur(180px)";
      context.fill();
      context.closePath();
    }
  }

  createDots();
}
```

Comment: createElement does not return an array `var c = document.createElement('canvas')[0];` <-- wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`createElement()` Is not an array of elements neither an array at all.

So you cannot use brackets on it. Remove the `[0]` from your function `createElement()`

like so :
 `document.createElement('canvas');`

Comment: Great, thanks! Solved a couple of errors after fixing this, but now I'm stuck here: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined. Any idea what would cause that?

Comment: Replace   : `document.getElementsByClassName('.jupiterx-site')[0].style.background = 'url(' + dataUrl + ')'`
by this :
  `document.getElementsByClassName('jupiterx-site')[0].style.background = 'url(' + dataUrl + ')'`

Comment: You where giving to your `getElementsByClassName` an query selector `.jupiterx-site` instead of the class name which is only `jupiterx-site`

Comment: Oh, okay that makes sense. I had switched out from a querySelector line. I'm still getting the same error, unfortunately.

Comment: For other problem and question feel free to make another post. If this answer you initial problem check the answer as solved to let the community know that it is.
You're free to make other question about other errors if you wish.